# Hotkey to print a variable in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

So I like to print variables when I program in order to debug (who doesn't).

It would be nice if I could select a variable and hit a hotkey which would write a print statement or copy it to my clipboard so I could paste it immediately. Is this achievable in Visual Studio. I've had a look at macros and code snippets and they don't seem to be made for this kind of thing. Will I have to write my own plug in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following C# command for my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension (and assign a hotkey to it) to show the selected variable value and copy it to the clipboard:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
{
EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
string variableName = ts.Text;
EnvDTE.Expression exp = DTE.Debugger.GetExpression(variableName);
string value = exp.Value;
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(value);
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(value);
}
```